# Update BIOS on T430s

Tags: bios

Does anyone know how I can update the BIOS on a T430s running Ubuntu 14.04? 
I have searched Lenovo support and Wiki pertaining to BIOS updates.

Comment: Some manufacturers provide bootable updates that can be installed from the BIOS setup. If that isn't given for you, then you'll have to either get Windows on there or live with your current BIOS version.

Comment: Thanks will probably have to dig up my copy of W7 where ever it may be.

Answer (score 0):

### BIOS update will not likely be supported from Linux (Ubuntu).

If you have a copy of the installer **.exe**, then try using a **FreeDOS** boot USB (created using **Rufus**). (see https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

*You will still need access to a Windows based PC (or laptop), to run Rufus on, and a spare USB drive.*